# Controller SpringMVC não redireciona pra outro controller

Tags: java, aplicação-web, java-ee, spring, spring-mvc

No Controller

LoginController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
private UsuarioRepositorio usuarioRepositorio;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String autenticar(@Valid @ModelAttribute Usuario usuario,
        BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, HttpSession session) {

    System.out.println("Logando...");
    Usuario user = new Usuario();
    UsuarioFactory uf = new UsuarioFactory();
    String retorno = "login/paginaLogin";
    String username = "";
    String autenticar = "";
    String msgErro = "";

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        throw new LoginInvalidException();
    } else {
        try {
            if (usuario.getUsername() == null) {
                if ((usuario.getEmail() != null)
                        && (!usuario.getEmail().isEmpty())) {
                    username = uf.gerarUsername(usuario.getEmail());
                }
            }

            if ((usuario.getUsername() != null)
                    && (!usuario.getUsername().isEmpty())) {
                username = usuario.getUsername();

                if (username.contains("@")) {
                    username = uf.gerarUsername(username);
                }

            }

            user = usuarioRepositorio.pegarUsuarioPeloUsername(username);

            if (user.getIdUsuario() > 0L) {
                String senha = "";

                senha = usuario.getSenha();

                autenticar = uf.chkAutenticar(user, senha);

                if (autenticar == "") {

                    model.addAttribute("usuarioLogado", usuario);
                    session.setAttribute("usuarioLogado", usuario);
                    retorno = "redirect:minhaConta/" + user.getIdUsuario();

                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            autenticar = "Usuário não encontrado";
        }

    }
    model.addAttribute("usuario", user);
    model.addAttribute("mensagemErro", autenticar);

    return retorno;

}
}
```

`recebe o retorno ="redirect:minhaConta/" + user.getIdUsuario();`

Que teoricamente deveria ir para o MinhaContaController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/minhaConta")
public class MinhaContaController {

@Autowired UsuarioRepositorio usuarioRepositorio;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "{idUsuario}")
public String minhaConta(@PathVariable Long idUsuario, Model model) {

    Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

    usuario = usuarioRepositorio.findOne(idUsuario);

    model.addAttribute("usuario", usuario);

    return "minhaConta/paginaMinhaConta";

}

}
```

Não dispara nenhuma `Exception` , porém não sai da tela de login, e os dados estão sendo passado normalmente.

Comment: Você tem certeza que a variável `retorno` tá recebendo a rota correta? Antes do `return` coloca um `System.out.println(retorno);` pra ver

Comment: @IgorVenturelli a variável `retorno` tá recebendo `redirect:minhaConta/8`, o "8" é o idUsuario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente o erro esta no if, quando você compara o autenticar com == ele compara a referencia do objeto, e não o conteúdo da string, podendo retornar false:

```
if (autenticar == "") { ...}
```

Não se usa == para comparar strings, use assim:

```
if ("".equals(autenticar)){...}
```

Comment: melhor ainda, utilize o método .isEmpty() para comparar se a String é vazia

Comment: Se ele usar o método .isEmpty() poder dar um NullPointerException caso a string seja nula

Comment: Utilizei e ainda persiste, o spring sabe que é pra redirecionar mas não faz essa ação

Comment: @TiagoFerezin tenta com "redirect:/minhaConta" ao invés de "redirect:minhaConta/"

Answer (score -2):

1. Substitua `autenticar == ""` por `autenticar.isEmpty()`.
2. Substitua `redirect:minhaConta/" + user.getIdUsuario();` por `redirect:/minhaConta/" + user.getIdUsuario();`.
3. Substitua `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "{idUsuario}")` por `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{idUsuario}")`.